# interp1 does not return expected results

Tags: arrays, matlab, linear-interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate the values of a vector but I can't seem to understand how to use interp1.m properly.

**This is what I'm expecting:**

```
a=[1 0 2 0 3 0 4];
//Use of interp1.m
Output=[1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4];

a=[1 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 4];
//Use of interp1.m
Output=[1 1.32 1.65 2 2.31 2.64 3 3.3 3.63 4];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you always want to fill the zero values of your vector:

```
a = [3 0 6 0 5 0 4]

mask = logical(a);
nvec = 1:numel(a);
a(~mask) = interp1(nvec(mask),a(mask),nvec(~mask))
```

---

```
a =

    3.0000    4.5000    6.0000    5.5000    5.0000    4.5000    4.0000
```

Assuming you want to *stretch* your vector by a certain factor:

```
a = [3 6 5 4]
stretchfactor = 2;
a = interp1((1:numel(a))*stretchfactor - 1, a, 1:numel(a)*stretchfactor - 1)
```

---

```
a =

    3.0000    4.5000    6.0000    5.5000    5.0000    4.5000    4.0000
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I think you meant to use `interp1`:

```
a=[1 2 3 4];
N=7; % # of points to interpolate between a(1)=1 and a(end)=4 
xi=linspace(a(1),a(end),N); % the new intep x-grid
ai=interp1(1:numel(a),a,xi)
```

As a side note, if you just want to have linear spacing between any two values, just use `linspace`, for example:

```
 linspace(1,4,10)


ans =

1.0000    1.3333    1.6667    2.0000    2.3333    2.6667    3.0000    3.3333    3.6667    4.0000
```

the zeros are real values that you entered, if you interpolate on them you "force" the result to pass through them...

Comment: This helps, but what if the vector is not linear? for example, I tried `a=[3 6 5 4]` and the output is `[3 3.167 3.34 3.50 3.67 3.84 4]`, but I wanted `[3 4.5 6 5.5 5 4.5 4]`

Comment: I think @bla 's solution should set `xi = linspace(1, numel(a), n)` instead.  This will give your expected results.